# How do I process PendingIntent in already running activity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a small app where the main activity is already in front and a notification may show. When the user taps on the notification I would like to have the main activity get the intent extras and act on them, but not sure how since it is already running.

My code that returns the PendingInent for use in the NotificationCompat.Builder:

```
private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctx, String brandId) {
    Intent showIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    showIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    showIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    showIntent.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true);
    showIntent.putExtra(BRAND_ID, brandId);

    return PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, showIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

I thought that maybe my MainActivity would be relaunched, but it isn't

How can I do this?

Comment: you can use return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, yourA.class);, 0);

Comment: You should remove the ACTION and CATEGORY from your `Intent`. These aren't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the "onNewIntent" method within your MainActivity class?

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //handle new intent here
}
```

As your activity is already running the new intent should come in here.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this  `onResume()....{   if(intent.getExtras().get("your_required_thing")!=null){ // do your stuff}` or you cant also use **broadCastReceiver** and register the receiver in onResume ... and get the intent extras at `onReceive` of broadcast

Answer (score 0):

```
private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctx, String brandId) {
    Intent showIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    showIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    showIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    showIntent.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true);
    showIntent.putExtra(BRAND_ID, brandId);
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, showIntent, 0);;
}
```

and then create broadcast class

```
public static class myNotificationCloseButtonHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Close Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, PlayerForegroundService.class);
            startIntent.setAction(PlayerForegroundService.STOP_FOREGROUND_ACTION);
            context.startService(startIntent);
        }


}
```